# Java Google Calendar API Order Events Descending

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-calendar-api

I would like to query for events.
I use the following code:

```
final Events feed = client.events().list(myCalendar.getId()).setOrderBy("updated").set("sortOrder", "descending")
    .execute();
```

This does not work, nevertheless.

How can I order the results **descending** instead of **ascending**?

My calendar has more than 250 events (maximum number of events returned), which is why I cannot just iterate over all events and need to do some pre-filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pagination to loop over additional rows.

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;

// ...

// Initialize Calendar service with valid OAuth credentials
Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
    .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

// Iterate over the events in the specified calendar
String pageToken = null;
do {
  Events events = service.events().list('primary').setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
  List<Event> items = events.getItems();
  for (Event event : items) {
    System.out.println(event.getSummary());
  }
  pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
} while (pageToken != null);
```

You can not choose ascending or descending by default its ascending. [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

> "updated": Order by last modification time (ascending).

Comment: Well that sucks :/